# Segmenting a column Data into multiple columns based on unique value in R

Tags: r, database, multiple-columns, data-transform

I have a dataset of the form:

[Dataset 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anpEe.png)

I need to convert the above data into the following in R:

[Dataset 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzkKg.png)

How can it be done? It should be simple but I am not able to figure out the correct function or steps to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use data.table for this:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.frame("A"=c(1,1,1,2,2),"B"=6:10)

df2 = data.table::dcast(df1,B~A,value.var="B")
```

[image]

Comment: np. :)
fyi, for next time, the way to go on stackoverflow is adding some code that creates the initial data frame (eg. df1 = data.frame("A"=c(1,1,1,2,2),"B"=6:10)), rather than a link to an image. tks & happy coding!